# Drupal 7 block configuration module

Tags: drupal

I have problems implementing module in drupal 7.

Whole module initially shows block with links to the five latest nodes made by current user, and in the configuration section user can change number of nodes that are shown.

I did manage to implement block that shows five latest nodes made by current user but I'm not managing to make block configuration work correctly.

First I made configuration form which looks like this:

```
function latest_posts_block_configure($delta = ''){
  $form = array();
  if($delta == 'latest_posts'){
    $form['latest_posts'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Number of recent content items to display'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('latest_posts', 3),
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
    );
  )
  return $form
}
```

This block configuration form works fine, but I don't know how to implement hook_block_save (that should (I guess) apply options chosen in configuration form).

My idea is to take the value selected from the form and to put it into sql query that extracts nodes but since I'm drupal beginner I am still struggling with it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless you are trying to learn, why don't you make a block with the views module? It will handle the queries for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7 could give you a hint. Then you may use the variable you set in configuration in your query.

Comment: I figured out how to get variable using hook_block_save but i don't know how to update my form (and query) with the new value. I tried using hook_block_view_alter but my try failed.

Comment: You may want to post some more details about what have you done so far. And +1 for the advice by @TKrugg

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I implemented hook_block_save() and I used variable_get/set() to modify query and update hook_block_view()